# How can I mock a function of other file that return a promise?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, automated-tests

I have function below. I can't test this function using Jest framework.

The function:

```
exports.example = async function (data) {

let utility;
  if (data.flag) {
    utility = require('./utility');
  } else {
    utility = require(Runtime.giveFunctions()['utility'].path);
  }
  const valueFromUtility = await utility.getValue(data);
     .
     .
     .
```

From the test I pass the data object that contains several properties, including:

- flag: if it is true I require the utility.js file and then I call the getValue (data) function, if it is false I get the path of the utility file that contains the getValue function and then I call the getValue (data) function.

If from the test pass data.flag === true the test is fine, otherwise (data.flag === false) the test fails telling me "utility.getValue is not a function".

In the utility.js file the getValue function returns a promise, as a parameter it has the data object which contains the mocked functions that will be called in getValue.

The test I wrote is the following:

```
test('Test with flag === false', async () => {

    jest.mock('../functions/utility', () => () => false);

    await example(data);

});
```

I also tried to mock the utility getValue function to return a resolved promise:

```
test('Test with flag === false', async () => {

    jest.mock('../functions/utility', () => jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve('Some values')));

    await example(data);

});
```

Finally, I mocked as follows:

```
const Runtime = {
    giveFunctions: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        utility: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            path: jest.fn()
        })
    })
};

window.Runtime = Runtime;
```

In the utility file I have only getValue function.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: `getValue` is not defined. The test code should be: `jest.mock('../functions/utility', () => ({ getValue: () => false }) );`

Comment: I have always the same problem :(

Comment: what are you trying to test by the way? in other words, what is your `expect(...)` statement?

Comment: I only call the function that I want to test. I only want to cover else statement. But I get the error when getValue is called with flag = false. (I think because I have mocked Runtime.utility.path and for this the getValue is not exists)

Comment: are you trying to increase the code coverage without testing anything?

Comment: Probably I'm following wrong way. If I can mocked getValue I can test the expectations. But I don't know how can do this. When I call example function in test I receive utility.getValue is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241900/discussion-between-marsab-and-kien-coi-1997).